# Java file upload applet - Suggestions needed

Tags: java

I want to build a simple file uploading applet in Java. It will be used to upload files to a regular linux web server. So if someone went to:

```
http://site.com/file-upload-applet
```

And uploaded a file there via the applet, it will be accessible at:

```
http://site.com/uploads/your-file.jpg
```

The user should be able to click 'Browse', and then look through the folders on his computer ,and be able to select as many files, or every file in a folder, if he wanted. Then, when he hits upload, he should be shown a progress bar while the files are uploaded.

Any thoughts about this, and how this could be accomplished in Java as an applet? I will just need some pointing in the right direction, such as which Libraries to use.

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to have a signed applet, as unsigned applets do not have access to the filesystem.

I found an [article about signed Applets](http://www.developer.com/java/data/article.php/3303561).

As for the other components, you'll most likely need a [JFileChooser](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html), [JProgressBar](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html), and a [JButton](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#abstractbutton) (that uses [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)'s [PostMethod](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/PostMethod.html) with a [MultipartRequestEntity](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/multipart/MultipartRequestEntity.html) that wrape the JFileChooser's file in a [FilePart](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/multipart/FilePart.html)).

Comment: once the applet is signed, how can i show them the browse button to let them pick the file? and how can i show a progress bar? which swing controls do i use, or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

I used the [Apache Commons File Upload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/), and it worked like a charm. It took away most of the problems I was worried about, and was very easy to use.